# not able to find right coordinates for top and left for a svg group path object in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, svg, transformation, fabricjs

I am using fabric js (1.4.0) for image editing, I have a functionality so that a user can create their personal templates, these templates will be created using fabric js and have rectangles, once the template is created then a user will be able to use these templates for creating collages, after selecting a template, a user will be able to select images which will be loaded inside that rectangle with the same height width, left and top, I found a way to set height and width but I am not able to find the left and top for that specific path object, in this case the rectangle which is the part of template svg group.

The code I am using for getting the path object is as follow

```
for (i = 0; i < canvas.getObjects().length; i++) {
            if (canvas.getObjects()[i].type == 'template') {
                imagePlaceholder = canvas.getObjects()[i].paths[1].transformMatrix;   
                canvas.getObjects()[i].paths.remove(canvas.getObjects()[i].paths[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Using the above code I am able to find the transformation matrix of the path object.

For finding out the height and width of the path object I am using code as mentioned below (while creating rectangle in templates I was using 100 px height and width)

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
            canvas.add(img).renderAll();
        }, {          
            opacity: 1,
            dataId: dataId,
            height: 100*imagePlaceholder[3],
            width: 100*imagePlaceholder[0],
        });
```

I know that the top and left are somehow related with elements imagePlaceholder[4] and imagePlaceholder[5] but I am not able to find the correct relation.